# What is the probability that the sequence of $n$ integers between $1$ and $n$ contains exactly $n-2$ different integers?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Suppose we choose a sequence $i_1,i_2,...,i_n$ of integers between 1 and n at random. What is the probability that the sequence contains exactly $n-2$ different integers?

I'm thinking that the solution will have $n \choose n-2$ possible sequences of length $n-2$ without repetition. Then, we need to choose $2$ out of the $n-2$ to repeat, which do not have to be distinct. So we have $(n-2)^2$ ways to pick these two integers that will be repeated. From this point forward, I'm not sure how to proceed. How do I get these into the sequence in a meaningful way. Or where did I go wrong when getting to this point?

Answer (score 3):

There are $n^n$ equally probable sequences

That exactly $(n-2)$ distinct numbers appear can be broken into 2 mutually exclusive cases...

Case 1: a single number is repeated 3 times and $(n-3) $ numbers appear once

- There are $ \binom n1$ choices for the number to repeat

  for each of these choices there are $ \binom {n-1}{n-3} =\binom
     {n-1}2 $ choices for the numbers that will appear only once

  for each of these choices there are $ \frac{n!}{3!}$ sequences that
  can be arranged

Case 2: 2 numbers are repeated twice and $(n-4) $ numbers appear once

- There are $ \binom n2$ choices for the two numbers to repeat

  for each of these choices there are $ \binom {n-2}{n-4} =\binom
     {n-2}2 $ choices for the numbers that will appear only once

  for each of these choices there are $ \frac{n!}{2!2!}$ sequences that
  can be arranged